# Cast CSV file to JSON using RxJava2

Tags: java, json, csv, rx-java2, vert.x

[UPDATED]
Hi 
I'd need to cast the content of a CSV file into a JSON mapped by a Java class, using RxJava2. So for example, the CSV looks like this:

```
1,John,Smith
```

And the **User** Java class includes the properties

```
Long id;
String name;
String surname;
```

I'm not expert of RxJava2 however I'm trying with the following:

```
vertx.fileSystem().rxReadFile("/home/user/file.csv")

        .map(buffer -> buffer.toString("UTF-8"))
        .map(n -> n.replace(","," "))
        .map(JsonObject::new)
        .map(json -> json.mapTo(User.class))
        .subscribe(
                content -> System.out.println("Content: " + content),
                err -> System.out.println("Cannot read the file: " + err.getMessage())
        );
```

However it seems I'm on the wrong track:

```
Failed to decode: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token
```

Any idea how to achieve it just using RxJava2 transformations?
Thanks

Comment: instead of .cast(JsonObject.class) try .map(JsonObject::new)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried and it seems the comma is not the default option as it requires a space to separate elements: Failed to decode: `Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): Expected space separating root-level values`

Comment: I've updated the progress in the original question

Comment: ohh i missed that your initial text is a csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at this completely wrong. There is no automatic/magical conversion between CSV and JSON. If you want to generate User object from the CSV you provided you can use following code:

```
vertx.fileSystem().rxReadFile("/home/lbulic/file.csv")
            .map(buffer -> buffer.toString("UTF-8"))
            .map(n -> n.split(","))
            .map(data -> new User(Long.parseLong(data[0]), data[1], data[2]))
            .subscribe(content -> System.out.println("Content: " + content),
                    err -> System.out.println("Cannot read the file: " + err.getMessage()));
```

You will need constructor for User object and also toString method in order for this for correctly.
If you want a JSON instead of the User object than the easy way is just to convert generated User object to JSON using Jackson.

```
rtx.fileSystem().rxReadFile("/home/lbulic/file.csv")
            .map(buffer -> buffer.toString("UTF-8"))
            .map(n -> n.split(","))
            .map(data -> new User(Long.parseLong(data[0]), data[1], data[2]))
            .map(user -> Json.encode(user))
            .subscribe(content -> System.out.println("Content: " + content),
                    err -> System.out.println("Cannot read the file: " + err.getMessage()));
```

For this to work you will also need getters and setters for the User object.

If you want direct conversion from CSV to JSON you will need to change the current structure of your CSV to something like this and will need to include additiona dependency.

CSV:

```
id,name,surname
1,John,Smith
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.builder().setUseHeader(true).build();
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

    vertx.fileSystem().rxReadFile("/home/lbulic/file.csv")
            .map(buffer -> buffer.toString("UTF-8"))
            .map(input -> csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(input).readAll())
            .map(list -> list.stream().map(Json::encode).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .subscribe(users -> {
                users.forEach(System.out::println);
            }, err -> System.out.println("Cannot read the file: " + err.getMessage()));
```